# golang background worker process inside api view

Tags: go, goroutine

We are planning to move to golang from django.

To send an email or sms, we do celery workers with redis/rabbotmq in Django. 
But how can we do that background tasks on golang.

Eg:

```
def api_view():

 // logic

 // celery tasks- call email/sms service

 // immediate response to client
 return Response()
```

How can we do in golang

```
fun ApiView(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){

 //logic

 // need to call email/sms service


 fmt.Fprintf(w, "TEST")
}
```

Is there anything we can start new go routine (without additional redis/workers) inside the API view of gorilla/mux ?

Thanks.

Comment: You start a new goroutine with a `go` statement, e.g. `go sendEmail(arg1, arg2)`. Read more [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements).

Comment: In Golang we dont need a concepts of message queue and worker threads like celery. ?

Comment: I don't know if *you* need a message queue or not, it depends on your requirements. If all you want to do is to execute some code asynchronously, then a goroutine should be enough. But if, for example you need to maybe offload background tasks to another machine, then you can use a message queue for that, and there are plenty of 3rd party client packages for the multitude of key-value stores, e.g. [redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) or message brokers, e.g. [amqp](https://github.com/streadway/amqp).

Comment: Clear explanation. but on the doc about goroutings " When the function terminates, its goroutine also terminates. " It means after view return the value to client the goroutine will be terminate without completion ?

Comment: No, the goroutine terminates when the function executed by the goroutine terminates, not the function that created the goroutine. When `sendEmail` terminates, the `go`routine terminates. When `ApiView` terminates it will not terminate `sendEmail` if it is still running.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/DgA_iCrW-xR

Comment: Great Thanks. I wrongly understand the termination of function. Basically when function terminates(sendEmail) the go routine completes.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: You might want to give https://github.com/jwells131313/goethe a try.  It gives you a function queue and a pool of threads along with other utilities you might find to ease the transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! As comments stated you can spawn a new go routine within the context of your view.  The goroutine gets its own stack and allows it to operate "asynchronously" from the view handling function:

```
func ApiView(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){

 //logic

 // need to call email/sms service
 go sendEmail(someEmailAddress)

 fmt.Fprintf(w, "TEST")
}
```

This will execute `sendEmail` using a go routine and immediately write `TEST` to the caller.

---

While trivial it is not equivalent to celery redis/rabbitmq:

- How do you handle failures?
- How do you bound concurrency (worker pool)
- How do you buffer tasks? (ie currently in rabbitmq it is out of process)
- How do you retry?
- Should the async task be in a different process/memory space?

None of the above are particularly difficult, and completely doable (and plenty of patterns/blogs/libraries exist for doing this exact thing)